# Are Bing Maps controls Internet-dependent?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Do Bing Maps controls depend on an Internet connection, or do they contain their world map as well as ability to zoom, scroll, and morph their presentation style (aerial, birdseye, road) "baked in" to the control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking for the silverlightcontrol: yes, the bingmap-control does not work without an internetconnection!
Moreover you need an API-Key, which legitimates your underlying dataaccess. Dataexchange relies on webservices.

Best regards

Comment: I'm not surprised, and I reckon it almost has to be that way; after all, the world is not static (especially its traffic, etc.)